# Update data in php using primary/foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Form script:

```
 <?php
// Inialize session
//session_start();
// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
/*if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
header('Location: form.html');
}*/
//connecting to the database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'online');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
//inserting Record to the database
$name = $_POST['name'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$cnic =  $_POST['cnic'];
$cellno = $_POST['cellno'];
$nationality = $_POST['nationality'];
$gender =  $_POST['gender'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$religion = $_POST['religion'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];

 if(!empty ($_POST['name']) && ($_POST['fname']) && ($_POST['cnic']) && ($_POST['cellno']) && ($_POST['nationality']) && (($_POST['gender']==='male')||($_POST['gender']==='female')) && ($_POST['dob']) && ($_POST['religion']) && (($_POST['city']==='Karachi')||($_POST['city']==='Isalamabad')||($_POST['city']==='Lahore')||($_POST['city']==='Rawalpindi'))  && ($_POST['adress']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
{
$query = "INSERT INTO basicinfo(name,fname,cnic,cellno,nationality,gender,dob,religion,city,adress)VALUES('$name','$fname','$cnic','$cellno','$nationality','$gender','$dob','$religion','$city','$adress')";
$update = "UPDATE basicinfo SET name='$name',fname='$fname',cnic='$cnic',cellno='$cellno',nationality='$nationality',gender='$gender',dob='$dob',religion='$religion',city='$city',adress='$adress' WHERE bid=";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$updateResult=mysql_query($update);
if($result && updateResult)
    {
        echo "Successfully updated database";
        header('Location: academicinfo.html');
    }
    else
    {
     die('Error: '.mysql_error($con));
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    }
    else{
    header('Location: basicinfo.html');
    }
if (isset ($_POST['neext']))
{
header ('location:academicinfo.html');
}

?>
```

This is my php code I want to update data but I don't know what to write in `where` clause because in MySQL database `bid` column is auto increment and it is foreign key please help me on this.

Comment: uhm, just out of curiosity, is there a reason why you would 'update' the row which you just have added recently. The insert query adds a new row, and the update just changes the recently created row with same data. It appears as an obsolete task.

Comment: `mysql_insert_id()`. However: **do not use the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` functions anymore**

Comment: `...WHERE bid=";` you need to add something there

Comment: mysql_insert_id() where to use this function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple just use this for your where condition. This will add another select onto your query but it's not that big of a hit since it's inline. Is that the table you are selecting from?

```
$update = "UPDATE basicinfo SET name='$name',fname='$fname',cnic='$cnic',cellno='$cellno',nationality='$nationality',gender='$gender',dob='$dob',religion='$religion',city='$city',adress='$adress' WHERE bid= (SELECT bid FROM basicinfo ORDER BY bid ASC LIMIT 1)";
```

Comment: i tried query you posted but this give error   Error: You can't specify target table 'basicinfo' for update in FROM clause

Comment: $update = "UPDATE basicinfo SET name='$name',fname='$fname',cnic='$cnic',cellno='$cellno',nationality='$nationality',gender='$gender',dob='$dob',religion='$religion',city='$city',adress='$adress' WHERE bid= (SELECT uid FROM users ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 1)";                                                       this   query i modified where uid is primary key from users table it update the basicinfo table but it  can't jump into next page  and it gives an error

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I guess I've been using frameworks for so long this type of problem doesn't come up anymore? Can you paste the error details in?

Comment: No error dteatil just simple display (Error) message

Comment: I won't be able to help you unless you can post some type of error. Don't you have an error log something has to be coming through there?

Comment: no just simple error displayed on my screen .no description about error